# Find string with RegEx

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, regex

I want to find a string in text for example Hello World in

> "Hello  World ,hello World,
>   Hello
>
> World"

I want to replace Hello World with Rock

> "Rock ,Rock, Rock"

Comment: any particular language?

Comment: Just check out the regex documentation for any language.It is the very first thing you will see.

Comment: Very good source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

Using perl

```
$ perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/[hH]ello.*?World/Rock/smg' input
"Rock ,Rock, Rock

"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace('/[(H|h)ello World]+/','Rock','Hello World ,hello World, Hello World')
```

Comment: but how i can make it more generic i mean i want  just give it the string value to look for not precisely Hello World

Comment: That regex doesn't do what you think it does.  You're supposed to use parentheses to form a group, not square brackets.  What you've got there is a character class that's equivalent to `[ HWdehlor()|]`.